# How to get previous URL?

Tags: java, jsf

I need the URL from which my web app is called. 
For eg:- If there is a link to my site foo.com from stackoverflow.com, I need the stackoverflow link in web app(managed bean).

All helps appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not always filled, but you can use:

```
HttpServletRequest.getHeader("Referer");
```

Note: The spelling error is on purpose. For an explanation see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer).

Comment: I had been trying with Referer for some time now, but its returning null. FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getRequest().getHeader("Referer")

Comment: As I said, it is not always filled. How are you creating the request? Using a browser? By clicking a link or by typing the URL?

Comment: @user757071 Try using a browser debugging tool such as Firbug for Firefox. It can show you all the request and response headers. You can see if the `Referer` header is present in the request after you have clicked a link.

Comment: @Qwerky, thanks for mentioning firebug. Referer header was not present.

Comment: Sorry, there is no other way. And it cannot be otherwise anyway, as not all URL requests are the result of someone clicking on a link.

Answer (score 1):

By checking the HTTP Referrer you can see from which site the request for your site originated.